# Finding the value of machine epsilon using python

Tags: python, precision

I wrote a simple code in python that gives me the same value of machine epsilon using the numpy command:np.finfo(float).eps
The code is:

```
eps=1
while eps+1 != 1:
    eps /= 2
    print(eps)
```

But I didn't want to stop here ! I used smaller and smaller numbers to divide eps, for example:

```
eps=1
while eps+1 != 1:
    eps /= 1.1
    print (eps)
```

With this, I got a value of 1.158287085355336e-16 for epsilon. I noticed that epsilon was converging to a number, my last attempt at 1.0000001 gave me the value of 1.1102231190697707e-16.

Is this value closer to the real value of epsilon for my Pc? I think I'm not considering something important and my line of thinking is wrong.

Thank you in advance for the help !

Answer (score 2):

The term “machine epsilon” is not consistently defined, so it's better to avoid that word and instead to say what specifically you're talking about:

1. **ulp(1)**, the magnitude of the least significant digit, or Unit in the Last Place, of 1.
   This is the distance from 1 to the next larger floating-point number.
   More generally, ulp() is the distance from  to the next larger floating-point number in magnitude.

   - In binary64 floating-point, with 53 bits of precision, ulp(1) is 2⁻⁵² ≈ 2.220446049250313 × 10⁻¹⁶.
   - In decimal64 floating-point, with 16 digits of precision, ulp(1) is 10⁻¹⁵.

   In general, for floating-point in radix  with  digits of precision (including the implicit 1 digit), ulp(1) = <sup>1 −</sup> .
2. The **relative error bound**, sometimes also called **unit roundoff** or **u**.
   A floating-point operation may round the outcome of a mathematical function such as  + , giving fl( + ) = ( + )⋅(1 + ) for some relative error .

   For basic arithmetic operations in IEEE 754 (+, −, *, /, sqrt), the result of computing the floating-point operation is guaranteed to be correctly rounded, which in the default rounding mode means it yields the nearest floating-point number, or one of the two nearest such numbers if  +  lies exactly halfway between them.

   - In binary64 floating-point, with 53 bits of precision, the relative error of an operation correctly rounded to nearest is at most 2⁻⁵³ ≈ 1.1102230246251565 × 10⁻¹⁶.
   - In decimal64 floating-point, with 16 digits of precision, the relative error of an operation correctly rounded to nearest is at most 5 × 10⁻¹⁶.

   In general, when floating-point arithmetic in radix  with  digits of precision is correctly rounded to nearest,  is bounded in magnitude by the relative error bound (/2) <sup>−</sup>.

What the Python iteration `while 1 + eps != 1: eps /= 2` computes, starting with `eps = 1.`, is the relative error bound in binary64 floating-point, since that's the floating-point that essentially all Python implementations use.

If you had a version of Python that worked in a different radix, say `b`, you would instead want to use `while 1 + eps != 1: eps /= b`.
If you do `eps /= 1.1` or `eps /= 1.0001`, you will get an approximation to the relative error bound erring on the larger side, with no particular significance to the result.

Note that `sys.float_info.epsilon` is ulp(1), rather than the relative error bound.
They are always related: ulp(1)/2 is the relative error bound in every floating-point format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the *actual* machine epsilon for a Python float on your PC, you can get it from the `epsilon` attribute of [`sys.float_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info). By the way, on my x86-64 machine, `numpy.finfo(float)` gives me `2.220446049250313e-16`, which is the expected machine epsilon for a 64-bit float.

Your intuition for trying to find the value `eps` such that `1 + eps != 1` is `True` is good, but machine epsilon is an *upper bound* on the *relative* error due to rounding in floating-point arithmetic. Not to mention, the inexact nature of floating-point arithmetic can be mystifying sometimes: note that `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 != 0.3` evaluates to `True`. Also, if I modify your code to

```py
eps = 1
while eps + 9 != 9:
    eps = eps / 1.0000001
print(eps)
```

I get, after around maybe half a minute,

```
8.881783669690459e-16
```

The relative error in this case is `8.881783669690459e-16 / 9 = 9.868648521878288e-17`.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is almost fine.

IT should be

```
eps=1
while eps+1 != 1:
   eps /= 2
print(2*eps)
```

The result is
2.220446049250313e-16

Which is the epsilon of the machine. You can check this with this piece of
code:

```
import sys
sys.float_info.epsilon
```

The reason we should multiply by 2 in the last line is because you went 1 division too far inside the while loop.